# How would I add markup inside of page title input?

Tags: 7

If I wanted to achieve the below, can I insert HTML markup inside of the page title on the node?

For example,

```
<h1 class="page-title">Dummy <span>page title</span> content</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [HTML Title](https://drupal.org/project/html_title). It will solve your issue.

> Drupal node titles are restrictive and do not support italicized text
>   or superscript text (e.g., Book titles, trademark symbols). The HTML
>   Title module allows a limited set of HTML markup (em, sub, sup, b, i,
>   strong, cite, code, bdi, wbr) to be used in node titles.

Also take a look at Stack Overflow question *[HTML\rich text in Drupal's node title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535878/html-rich-text-in-drupals-node-title)*.